# How to run python script simultaneously when user input in Django REST api?

Tags: python, django

I am very new in Django REST API and Python.
I have python script. and I created simple Django REST API for getting input from users.

Now I want to do when user give input through Django REST API then after run my python script with it. so I want to integrate my python script with Django REST API.

I tried to do googling but Not able to understand because in some forum they use `subprocess` and in some forum given `REQUEST` function. I am confuse and not able to understand.

my **view.py** file as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import viewsets
from . models import input_params
from . serializers import input_paramsSerializer

class inputViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = input_params.objects.all()
    serializer_class = input_paramsSerializer
```

**url.py** file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from base_search.views import inputViewSet
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'input',inputViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^',include(router.urls))
]
```

**Question1**

Now can anyone please tell me How can I connect my python script here?

**Question2:**

if I just connect my python script at endpoint so will it take automatically user input data from Django REST API and run my python script?

If anyone have good example please let me know.

Comment: why you need to use srcipt instead of simple create any python funcytion and call it?

Comment: Thanks for comment but I already made python script and it contains some function and i need to do some analysis work on user input. thatsy

Comment: what about `import`?

Comment: `import` what should I import ? Do I need to Import File in **view.py** ?

Comment: yes `import` your file inside your view

Comment: Hi as you suggest I imported file in **view.py** file. but it give me error
my code in `python_code` folder and script name is `myscript`. I created small function call `run` in it so I am calling that function.

    `from python_code.myscript import run`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_code'`

Comment: add you new code and error to the question

Comment: Hi I just moved python `script` from `python_code` folder to `App` folder and it works but Now I don't know how to get user input in my python code and run python script. 
Also I want to see the output. Can you please tell me how can I do?

Comment: the same comment, show your new code, and may be it is time to create new question instead of create many comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *subprocess* to achieve the desired functionality.

> The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.
>
> The underlying process creation and management in this module is handled by the Popen class.

```
import sys
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['myscript.py', 'arg1', ...], ..., shell=True)
```

You can use also use something like:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("<your_script>.py arg1 arg2")
#p will have your detailed result output, 
#you can then proceed with this variable for further decision making
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but can you please elaborate it because I am very new in Django. 
I tried to make small script who just print all parameters and write code as u suggest in view.py file but it not showing desire output
Can you please little elaborate your answer so It will be very helpful for me

Comment: No not yet I did from basic "GET" and "POST" method and just wrote Python code in POST method . Still I want to learn how to import directly python code in API

Comment: One more way is to take an object oriented approach and transform your existing python codes into classes and directly import them :)